# How can I change multiple rows to NA for a "check all that apply" question?

Tags: r

I have a question in my survey that is check all. It asks:
What animals did you own growing up? (check all that apply)

- Cat
- Dog
- Rabbit
- Guinea pig
- Mouse
- None

The survey was collected in RedCap, so each time a question was checked, it was labeled at "Yes" and if it was left unchecked it was labeled as "no". Each answer (dog, cat, etc) is a different column in my dataset (`column_cat`, `column_dog`).

The problem that I have is that not everyone answered this question. Some people skipped it by accident. This means that these skipped questions in R are labeled at "No" when in actuality they should be `NA` because none of the six possible answers have been checked.

Is there any easy way to quickly recode all this missing data as `NA` for each variable? I have several variables like this, so I am hoping there is a quick(ish) solution

I think I might possibly be able to use the function `replace_with_na_if()` but I am not sure what is the most efficient approach.

Comment: Provide your example data `dput(head(mydata))`, something like this should work: `ifelse(rowSums(mydata[, petcolumns] == "No") == numberofpets, NA, mydata$petBinary)`

Answer (score 0):

With this example data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  column_cat = c("Yes", "No", "No"),
  column_dog = c("Yes", "No", "No"),
  column_none = c("No", "Yes", "No")
)

dat
#   column_cat column_dog column_none
# 1        Yes        Yes          No
# 2         No         No         Yes
# 3         No         No          No
```

You can use `dplyr::if_all()` to test across multiple columns, and `dplyr::across()` to modify them:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(
    column_cat:column_none,
    \(x1) ifelse(
      if_all(column_cat:column_none, \(x2) x2 == "No"), 
      NA, 
      x1
    )
  ))
#   column_cat column_dog column_none
# 1        Yes        Yes          No
# 2         No         No         Yes
# 3       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
```